# What are the best possible ways of indicating a 'closed' trail?

Tags: hiking, trekking, trails

I live in a region where you have trails that are open any time of the year, some of the other trails are usable throughout the year except rainy (monsoon) season.
There are also rare cases of the trails with sharp slopes regarding which trekkers are advised against using them in Summers (due to extremely dry weather causing soil and grass drying which turns into a extremely difficult section to pass through).
In our region, people typically have got familiar with marking of trails by best natural ways instead of signboards (which are very rare).

What are the best possible ways to indicate a 'closed' trail?

To start with, what I have seen for decades now, villagers usually put a huge branch of thorny bush on the trail so that no cattle (or a trekker) continue to walk.

Comment: Hmm, I find this difficult, maybe it just doesn't apply to where I live. In the UK trails (rights of way) are in law and can't be closed. If you do get a suspension of a trail, you need permission from the local government, you have to show an alternate route and put up explicit signs saying where the new route goes, etc. So trails don't get closed.

Comment: Any qualms about just bringing good old-fashioned "DANGER" caution tape with you to mark that dangerous area off? Is this your property or are you just trying to look out for other travelers after you notice a bad spot of trail? Do you have a forestry service or DNR (Department Of Natural Resources) type organization to contact to get them to put official signs up?

Comment: The branch/bush in front of a trail is what I've always seen when people want to signal a trail is closed.

Answer (score 5):

A trail closed sign on a post or tree.

[image: sign]

Comment: Related [How to attach signs to trees considering tree growth?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/7969)

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest a closure notice showing the reason and the time-period.

[image]

Explaining the closure makes it more likely that people will understand the reason and comply.

In the Western Alps you sometimes come across chord or tape across a trail with no reason given, which makes it difficult to evaluate whether to ignore it or not.

The alternative to a notice would be some kind of a physical barrier, but this would likely hamper local people going about their business.